# Application breaks while get set of property in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin. I have created a test app where a data in text field will update a label, when I set label value static via model, it works well but when i try to update label value dynamically the application breaks.

```cs
class Properties : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Res { get; set; } // This works fine.
    public string Dept 
    {
        get { return Dept; } /// This cause the application to break whithout even notifying any error
        set
        { 
            if (Dept != value)
            {
                Dept = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Dept ));
            }
        } /// This cause the application to break whithout even notifying any error
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var propertyChangedCallback = PropertyChanged;
        propertyChangedCallback?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you have a infinite loop.

This is because you are accessing the property `Dept` in its own getter and setter. This will infinitely try to call the getter or setter and eventually crash.

To solve this you have to add a backing field like:

```cs
private string _dept;
public string Dept
{
    get => _dept;
    set
    {
        if (_dept != value)
        {
            _dept = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Dept));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was screwed for 3 hrs. Didn't know I just missed a small imp part.